# unable to call a local module from an application file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-applications

I am beginner in node.js.

I am trying to call a very basic addition module saved in C:\wks\guru99 with file name: Node_03_addition.js. The calling application is also saved in the same location with the name: app.js

Addition Module:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
exports.addNumber=function(a,b)
{
return a+b;
};
```

Application File:

```
var Addition = require('/.Node_03_addition.js');

console.log(Addition.addNumber(1,2));
```

when I run the application in cmd using node app.js

I am receiving the error that Module is not found. Can someone please help me with where I am going wrong here.

```
c:\wks\guru99>node app.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/.Node_03_addition.js'
Require stack:
- c:\wks\guru99\app.js
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)[39m
[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\wks\guru99\app.js:1:16)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: [ [32m'c:\\wks\\guru99\\app.js'[39m ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the file `.Node_03_addition.js` in relation to `app.js`?  And, do you really have a file whose filename starts with `.`?  Perhaps, it is supposed to be `require('./Node_03_addition.js');`

Comment: Your export declaration is the issue. See suggestion in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

```
// Node_03_addition.js
// Declare your function
const addNumber = function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
};

// Export your function
module.exports = {
    addNumber
};

// Application-File.js
// Import your module
const Addition = require('./Node_03_addition');

// Use it
console.log(Addition.addNumber(1,2)); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition Module:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
exports.addNumber=function(a,b)
{
return a+b;
};
```

Application File:

```
var Addition = require('./Node_03_addition.js');

console.log(Addition.addNumber(1,2));
```

Comment: you mislead file path and Addition is a module not a function